# Interpretation of an axiom

Tags: logic, category-theory

Quoting authors: 
“If $T$ is any object in $C$, and $a:T \rightarrow A$ and $s:T \rightarrow S$  are maps satisfying $h \circ a=j \circ s$, then $p \circ a=s$”.

More information regarding $h, p, j$:

$h: A \rightarrow B$, $p: A \rightarrow S$ and $j: S \rightarrow B$ ($j$ is an inclusion map)

My interpretation:
If $T \in C$ such that $a: T \rightarrow A$ and $s: T \rightarrow S$ satisfy $h \circ a = j \circ s$, then $p \circ a = s$.

Is my interpretation equivalent to author's statement of an axiom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author's axiom is a condition on triples $(h,p,j)$: they satisfy the axiom if, for every diagram of the form $A \xleftarrow{a} T \xrightarrow{s} S$, if $h \circ a = j \circ s$, then $p \circ a = s$. In this axiom, the object $T$ and the maps $a$ and $s$ are universally quantified: symbolically, it appears to say
$$\forall T \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{C}),\, \forall a : T \to A,\, \forall s : T \to S,\, h \circ a = j \circ s \Rightarrow p \circ a = s$$

Your interpretation, as phrased, quantifies the object $T$ but does not quantify $a,s$; you appear to be saying:
$$\forall T \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{C}),\ h \circ a = j \circ s \Rightarrow p \circ a = s$$

These are not equivalent, since $a$ and $s$ are free variables in the latter and (universally quantified) bound variables in the former.

Comment: Agreed. But after that, my question was "Why is quantification of $a: T \rightarrow A, s: T \rightarrow S$ necessary?". I think, then I am not clear about what I am talking about, when I say $(h \circ a = j \circ s) \Rightarrow (p \circ a =s)$. Is it about only one pair of specific pair of maps $s, a$ or any arbitrary pair $s, a$? In other words, What if, for a triplet $(h, j, p)$, $\forall T \in obj(C), \exists (s, a)$ such that $(h \circ a = j \circ s) \Rightarrow (p \circ a =s)$. Does this particular $(h, j, p)$ satisfy the axiom? Thus, we need quantification. Right?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking now. The quantification implicit in the author's wording is $\forall T \in C,\ \forall (s,a),\ (h \circ a = j \circ s) \Rightarrow (p \circ a = s)$, and not $\forall T \in C,\ \exists (s,a),\ \dots$.

Comment: Right, I agree. But, what I want to know is a reason for necessity of quantification. What happens, if we do not quantify (Take for instance, my interpretation of author's axiom)? That is what I attempted to explain in my comment. By the way, you have already answered the question initially posted about equivalency of statements. Thanks for that.

Comment: If you don't quantify the variables, then the two statements have different free variables and so it doesn't make sense to ask if they're equivalent. For example, consider the statements "For all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $2x+y$ is even" and "For all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2x+y$ is even". The first statement has one free variable, namely $y$; the latter has no free variables (and is true). (cont...)

Comment: Asking if they're equivalent is the same as asking if "For all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $2x+y$ is even" is true, but that is a nonsensical question, because its truth value depends on $y$: if $y=4$ then it's true, if $y=3$ then it's false, if $y$ is universally quantified then it's false, if $y$ is existentially quantified then it's true. The same issue arises with your question: if two statements have different sets of free variables, then you can't ask if they're equivalent.

Comment: I think, now I understand. Consequently, for a triplet $(h, j, p)$, a particular truth value cannot be assigned to the statement $(h\circ a= j \circ s) \Rightarrow (p \circ a = s)$, as it will depend upon choice of maps $a$ and $s$ for an object $T \in C$. However, in context of author's statement of the axiom, knowing $(h, j, p)$ and category $C$, one may decide if $(h, j, p)$ satisfies the axiom or not, as there are no free variables.

Comment: That sounds about right, yes :)